# Column not found exception when trying to create new user with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

My application throws the following exception when I try to insert a new user entity:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.username AS
>   username2, t1.username_canonical AS username_canonical3, t1.email AS
>   email4, t1.email_canonical AS email_canonical5, t1.enabled AS
>   enabled6, t1.salt AS salt7, t1.password AS password8, t1.last_login AS
>   last_login9, t1.locked AS locked10, t1.expired AS expired11,
>   t1.expires_at AS expires_at12, t1.confirmation_token AS
>   confirmation_token13, t1.password_requested_at AS
>   password_requested_at14, t1.roles AS roles15, t1.credentials_expired
>   AS credentials_expired16, t1.credentials_expire_at AS
>   credentials_expire_at17, t1.id AS id18, t1.nom AS nom19 FROM etudiant
>   t1 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ?' with params ["dar"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   't0.username_canonical' in 'where clause'

User:

```
<?php

namespace Esprit\UserBundle\Entity;
use Esprit\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="Student ")
*/
 class Student extends User
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

 /**
 *@ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 */

private $nom;

}
```

config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
     user_class: Esprit\UserBundle\Entity\Student
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you run `app/console doctrine:schema:update` ? Did you clear your cache? There seems to be a typo/*missing space* in your user class - `Student extends User`. Was that a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: yes i clear the cash , and the two classes are fine , i think i should change the providers in the security.yml no ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so I solved the problem,we should extend from  BaseUser

```
class Student extends BaseUser
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the discriminator for your User class with this :

```
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"student" = "Student", "employee" = "Employee"})
```